# asmx service with silverlight VS2013

Tags: web-services, silverlight

I had created my Silverlight solution with **vs2010** and now I have converted it to **vs2013** in this situation when I give service (I have used **asmx** service) reference in my project then it gives following errors:

> Error 14  The type 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs' exists in both
>
> 'c:\Users\kabir\Desktop\GM\GarmentsModel 12Apr 2013\GarmentsModel\Bin\Debug\System.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll' and
>
> 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\System.Windows.dll'

What is my wrong. It was my running project.

Answer (score 0):

The class `NavigationEventArgs` is defined for Windows and for Silverlihgt. It's defined in PresentationFramework.dll.

For some reason one of your projects seams to reference both DLL's. Your server side code should only reference to the Windows dll's, your client side code (the Silverlight project) should only reference to Silverlight DLL's.

Look in which project the error is raised and check it's references.